# Can I merge all possible travel modes in a single result from Google maps API?

Tags: api, google-maps

I tried all travel modes like driving, walking, cycling, etc., But I want all travel modes displayed in a single result on my routing feature. Is this possible?

Comment: All travel modes. Please help :(